# Tailwind on my next.js project works only after refresh on some pages while works fine on other

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, git-merge

I am working on a Next.js project with other contributor, when i am on my pages, my Tailwind works fine but when I move to their pages and revert back to mine the tailwind breaks down and works correctly after a refresh.

I am working on a Next.js project with other contributor, when i am on my pages, my Tailwind works fine but when I move to their pages and revert back to mine the tailwind breaks down and works correctly after a refresh.I want the tailwind to work properly. Is it an issue in merging or something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.